# JPA entities to JSON

Tags: hibernate, rest, jpa, moxy

Automatic conversion of JPA entities to JSON leads to HTTP 500 Internal server error in Glassfish.

The conversion works fine when the inner mapped entities are empty but when they are linked I get the error.

These are the entities, service and REST resource.

I have viewed other thread about the same topic but couldn't understand properly. I am a newbie programmer.

Flight.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightDestinations flightOrigin;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightDestinations flightDestination;

    private Integer price;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date flightTime;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "airplane_fk")
    private Airplane airplaneDetails;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight")
    @XmlTransient
    private List<Pilot> pilots;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "f_p_join", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "flight_fk"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "passenger_fk"))
    private List<Passenger> passengers;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Passenger.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Passenger implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightClass flightClass;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "passengers")
    private List<Flight> flights;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Pilot.java

```
@Entity
public class Pilot implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Integer pilotLicense;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PilotRank pRank;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_fk")
    private Flight flight;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Airplane.java

```
@Entity
public class Airplane implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String planeMake;

    private String modelName;

    private Integer seatinCapacity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="airplaneDetails")
    private Flight flightDetails;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Method to get all Flights from database in service class

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "airline")
    EntityManager em;

public List<Flight> getFlights() {

        TypedQuery<Flight> query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Flight f", Flight.class);
        List<Flight> results = query.getResultList();


        return results;
        }
```

REST method

```
@EJB
FlightService fs;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Flight> getFlights() {

    List<Flight> fList = fs.getFlights();       
    return fList;

}
```

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: @otonglet HTTP 500 internal server error.

Comment: usually there is a stacktrace coming with those 500 errors. Could you paste it here ?

Comment: what has JPA got to do with this? You have some process to convert objects to JSON, using MOXY presumably based on your tags? hence the problem is presumably there ... and not in JPA

Comment: @otonglet There was nothing. Just got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OneaH.png

Comment: That's what the server replies indeed. But you should be able to find some logs on the server side. You can browse your application server documentation to know how to look for them.

Comment: Couldnt find anything in "C:\gfish10\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log" . When there is no link between Flight and Passenger I get this json 

[{"id":1,"flightOrigin":"Dubai","flightDestination":"USA","price":5000,"flightTime":"2017-02-01T05:30:30.357+05:30","airplaneDetails":{"id":2,"modelName":"636","planeMake":"Boeing","seatinCapacity":5000},"pilots":[],"passengers":[]}]

Comment: But after linking Flight to Passenger I get HTTP 500 and just this in server.log


[2017-02-07T19:32:12.961+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1486476132961] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Flight web service [Flight [id=1, flightOrigin=Dubai, flightDestination=USA, price=5000, flightTime=Wed Feb 01 05:30:30 IST 2017, airplaneDetails=Airplane [id=2, planeMake=Boeing, modelName=636, seatinCapacity=5000], pilots={IndirectList: not instantiated}]]]]

Comment: Most probably your error has to do with the JoinColumn MainToOne.
By default in hibernate join columns are lazy thus when it comes to serialization there is no jpa session to be found since you seem to be out of a transaction scope. A stacktrace would help.